# Replacing a HP P410 RAID Card

Tags: raid, hp, hardware-raid, hp-smart-array

I'm getting kernel panics and I'm suspecting it's the RAID card locking itself up based on the messages in the panic log. I'm not sure if it's really the card or not.

When it boots back up, it says there was a controller error: "A controller failure event occured prior to this power-up. (Previous lock up code 0xab)"

Here is the kernel panic log: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8dML.png

So, I'm looking to replace the RAID Card but I'm not sure if I'm able to just physically replace the card and the raid array gets detected automatically and the configuration imported to the new RAID card.

What procedure should I follow?

Comment: Do You have the latest firmware version installed on the controller ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can replace a Smart Array controller with a like-model. The array configuration and metadata are on the disks, not the controller.

More questions...

- What type of server is this? I need the make and model of the system.
- If this is not an HP server, how long have you had it in this configuration?
- What specific operating system and release are you using?
- What type of disks are connected to the controller?
- Do you have cache and a battery or flash capacitor unit on the controller?

Depending on the answer to that question, your solution could be as simple as firmware or as complex as a system board replacement.

The [HP Smart Array P410 RAID controller](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/servers/proliantstorage/arraycontrollers/smartarrayp410/) is often embedded on the system board (known as the P410i). It was the standard controller for G6 and G7 HP ProLiant servers and has a solid track record. I've only had to replace one or two out of a few thousand systems over the years.

This controller is also available as a standalone PCIe card, the P410. This was how the card was delivered with HP 100-series ProLiant servers.

If you are having problems, please update the firmware for the controller and related components. If this is an HP server, you can use the SPP bootable DVD. Otherwise, [the firmware page for the controller is here](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/public/psi/swdHome/?cc=us&cc=us&lang=en&lang=en&sp4ts.oid=3984646&ac.admitted=1389559492067.876444892.492883150).

- If this is an embedded controller, you may be due for a system board replacement.
- If this is a standalone controller, you may just have to replace the controller.
- This may just be a cache module failure on the controller.

Comment: It's a HP DL180 G6
Debian Wheezy 64Bit
12 x 4TB SATA Drives + 1 x 4TB as hot spare
Yes, a 1GB one.

I've upgraded the backplane's and raid card's firmware last week. Today, it happened again.

   Cache Status Details: The current array controller had valid data stored in its battery/capacitor backed write cache the last time it was reset or was powered up.  This indicates that the system may not have been shut down gracefully.  .....

Comment: Then replace the card. Your data should be intact on the disks.

Comment: Should I just replace the card or the BBU and cache as well to be safe?

Comment: Try without the cache now... see if it works.

Comment: I've just replaced the card, bbu, cache and cable and I didn't even have to login to IPMI. It imported all the config automatically. Let's see if the problem continues.

Comment: unfortunately, I'm still having the same issue after replacing the raid card, the cables, the cache memory and the BBU. I'm looking to replace the whole server system (DL180 G6). Would it be okay if I create the exact same configuration as this server and install the disks to it?