# Replacing HP P410 with P420 and keeping the data

Tags: raid, hp, hp-proliant, hardware-raid, hp-smart-array

Would it be possible to replace HP P410 raid card with a HP P420 raid card while keeping the data?

I've replaced P410 with P410 without any issues obviously. I believe they use the same software, so I'm guessing this would be possible.

If I were to try it, can I go back to P410 if P420 replacement doesn't work?

Comment: Why do you want to replace your RAID controller? Please give more context on what you're doing and what the real problem is.

Comment: Is this related to your [question from last year](http://serverfault.com/questions/566760/replacing-a-hp-p410-raid-card)?

Comment: @ewwhite No, it's not related. I didn't have a spare P410 at that time and wanted to see if P420 would work as replacement.

Answer (score 2):

From the [P420 QuickSpecs](http://h20195.www2.hp.com/v2/GetDocument.aspx?docname=c04111534&doctype=quickspecs&doclang=EN_US&searchquery=&cc=us&lc=en):

> **Data Compatibility** among most current shipping Smart Array controllers
>   allows simple and easy upgrades any time needs for higher performance,
>   capacity, and availability increase. Even successive generations of
>   Smart Array controllers understand the data format of other Smart
>   Array Controllers.

So it would appear that it should just work.

As always, do make sure you have good backups and if you are unsure of the compatibility do contact the vendor.

Comment: I wouldn't advise this blindly without knowing the type of server involved or the reason for the controller change.

Answer (score 2):

The on-disk RAID format of HP Smart Array controllers and disk sets are the same between the P410 and P420 controller.

The bigger questions are:

- What server model and generation are you using? Is this related to [your question from 2014](https://serverfault.com/questions/566760/replacing-a-hp-p410-raid-card)? The P410 controller is linked to G6 and G7 ProLiant servers, while the Gen8 servers use the P420 controller.
- Why do you want to change the controller? Are you having a performance or support problem? In most cases these controllers are embedded in the motherboard. Standalone P420 controllers aren't especially common, so I'd like to understand the context here.
- What operating system and revision are you using? The HP controllers can use the same OS driver, assuming it is new enough to support the P420.

Comment: I'm successfully using P420 on G6 and G7 servers for more than a year. So I figured I could just replace it with a P410 on a G6 server.

Comment: You haven't explained why you're trying to do this. Sure, it will work, but I can't think of any reason you'd want to change the controller.